# How LIKE operation performed with MySQL In sails?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to fetch related data from a table in sails. But it shows me some errors.

Here is code.

```
let category = req.param('category');
        let q = req.param('search_box');
        console.log(category); //actor_1
        console.log(q); //j

        let qry = `SELECT * from getdatafromurl WHERE ${category} like %${q}%`;
        let data = await GetDataFromURL.getDatastore().sendNativeQuery(qry);

        console.log(data);
```

**ERROR**

> Error: Query failed: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '%j%' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved...
I just forgot the comma in **%${q}%**.

**Change it**

```
let qry = `SELECT * from getdatafromurl WHERE ${category} like %${q}%`;
```

**New**

```
let qry = `SELECT * from getdatafromurl WHERE ${category} like '%${q}%'`;
```